# How to use a pipe to dynamically exclude options from a primeNG dropdown

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using `PrimeNG 15` with `Angular 14`. I have two multi select dropdowns. The options for dropdown 1 (source city) come from list 1, and the options for dropdown 2 (destination city) come from list 2. The requirement is that the source city and destination city must not be the same. Therefore, I want the city selected in dropdown 1 to be excluded from the options in the dropdown.

2. My code looks like this:

```
<p-dropdown
  [options]="sourceCities"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedSourceCity"
  optionLabel="name">
</p-dropdown>

<p-dropdown
  [options]="destinationCities"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedDestinationCity"
  optionLabel="name">
</p-dropdown>

constructor() {
  this.sourceCities = [
    {name: 'New York', code: 'NY'},
    {name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'},
    {name: 'London', code: 'LDN'},
    {name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'},
    {name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}
  ];

  this.destinationCities = [
    {name: 'New York', code: 'NY'},
    {name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'},
    {name: 'London', code: 'LDN'},
    {name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'},
    {name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}
  ];
}
```

I tried creating a pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'excludeValue'
})
export class ExcludeValuePipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    return value.filter(function (item) {
       console.log(args)
        return item.id != args; 
    });
    }
}
```

There are two problems with my pipe:

1. It doesn't work for multiple values.
2. I don't know how to use a pipe on a PrimeNG dropdown.

Please feel free to suggest any other approach without using the pipe.

I'm not getting any answers on Google. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you disable the second dropdown item? It's an easier and cleaner way, you can use `optionGroupLabel` in primeng. You can listen to `ngModelChange` event of `sourceCities` and then disable them in `destinationCities`.

Comment: You can achieve what you want by a simple filter-method that is triggered whenever a new `sourceCity` is selected. Just listen to the `onChange` event on the `sourceCities` dropdown. I briefly created a working example which I could post here, but since you specifically ask for a pipe, you are only limiting yourself unnecessarily.

Comment: @kellermat, you're right. Please ignore the pipe part in the question. I just need a working solution. Thanks

Comment: @Tanzeel: OK, I just suggested an edit of your title so that it doesn't imply that you are specifically looking for a pipe-solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final requirements were as follows:

- The selected `sourceCity` shall not be selectable as `destinationCity`
- The selected `destinationCity` shall not be selectable as `sourceCity`
- No initial value shall be selected

I would propose the solution below.

First the **ts-part**:

```
cities: City[];
selectedSourceCity: City;
selectedDestinationCity: City;

constructor() {

    this.cities = [
        {name: 'New York', code: 'NY'},
        {name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'},
        {name: 'London', code: 'LDN'},
        {name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'},
        {name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}
    ];
}

get filteredSourceCities() {
    return this.cities.filter(c=> c.code !== this.selectedDestinationCity?.code);
}

get filteredDestinationCities() {
    return this.cities.filter(c=> c.code !== this.selectedSourceCity?.code);
}
```

Then the **html-part**:

```
<h5>Source City</h5>
<p-dropdown [options]="filteredSourceCities"
            [(ngModel)]="selectedSourceCity"
            [autoDisplayFirst]="false"
            optionLabel="sourceCity">
</p-dropdown>

<h5>Destination City</h5>
<p-dropdown [options]="filteredDestinationCities"
            [(ngModel)]="selectedDestinationCity"
            [autoDisplayFirst]="false"
            optionLabel="destinationCity">
</p-dropdown>
```

By setting `[autoDisplayFirst]="false"`, no initial value is selected.

Comment: Its working but just one more requirement. Can we have this check on both the side vice versa also. And also i would like the dropdowns to be blank when the page loads.

Comment: @Tanzeel: I think I have found a much simpler solution where the dropdowns are interdependent. The `onChange` event is not even needed.

Comment: Btw: I assumed that both dropdowns initially provide thd same options. Yet if this is not the case I could easily adapt my solution: The two filter methods would then use a separate city-array.

Comment: This answer solved my answer and provided complete explanation.